# How to do predicate logic in Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages, homework, logic

I'm trying to formalize and analyze the following reasoning:

1. All equilateral triangles are isosceles triangles.
2. Some triangles are not equilateral triangles.
3. Therefore some triangles are not isosceles triangles.

The reasoning is obviously not valid. But I tried to find that out with *Mathematica*. So I typed what I would type in my math notebook:

```
Resolve[Implies[
  SubsetEqual[equilateralTriangles, isoscelesTriangles] &&
   Exists[triangle, NotElement[triangle, equilateralTriangles]]
  , Exists[triangle, NotElement[triangle, equilateralTriangles]]]]
```

and I got:

> Resolve::elemc: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition triangle ∉ equilateralTriangles. >>
>
> ```
> Resolve[equilateralTriangles \[SubsetEqual] isoscelesTriangles && \!\(
> \*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(triangle\)]\(triangle \[NotElement] 
>      equilateralTriangles\)\) \[Implies] \!\(
> \*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(triangle\)]\(triangle \[NotElement] 
>     equilateralTriangles\)\)]
> ```

Am I doing this the right way? Can one solve problems like this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: *SubsetEqual* has no meaning, for starters. It's there for output convenience, or can be overloaded with user-written functionality...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: your syllogism should probably be formulated as

```
Resolve[
  Implies[
    ForAll[triangle, 
      Implies[
        Element[triangle, equilateralTriangles], 
        Element[triangle, isoscelesTriangles]]] && 
      Exists[triangle, NotElement[triangle, equilateralTriangles]], 
    Exists[triangle, NotElement[triangle, isoscelesTriangles]]]]
```

but that still produces the `Resolve::elemc` message.

To answer your second question: I don't think so. *Mathematica* can only apply the predicate calculus to points in geometric regions or numerical domains, not totally abstract sets, and that is what the message `Resolve::elemc` is trying to tell you. See the documentation for[`Exists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exists.html)